# WinJS changing a template's element for a specedicitem in ListView

Tags: javascript, data-binding, microsoft-metro, winjs

Here we go , this is my question and i can't find anything to resolve it.
The problem that i have this template(for data-Binding) for my Gridview:

```
<div id="mytemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div id="questions" class="tweet">
        <img src="#" style="-ms-grid-row-span: 2; width: 64px; height: 64px; margin-right: 10px;" data-win-bind="src:picture_url">
        <h2 style="width:auto;-ms-grid-column: 2; -ms-grid-column-span: 1; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 0px; -ms-grid-row-span: 2;" data-win-bind="textContent:type"></h2>   
        <label id="answer" ">Message</label>            
      </div>    
</div>
```

In all items , i have Message as a label 
So when i click to an item , in the  itemInvokedHandler(eventObject) function , i make show a Flyout which contains an input text and i want that this  label will change from my input text field from the Flyout.What is the solution for that.
Just , i am thinking about moving the label tag outside of the  template but it's not logical because it want a label for each item.
Any suggestion or help will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that best option is to use a MVVM approach: Bind every item to an entity and have this entity expose an observable property named Text, bind Flyout to another observable property SelectedItem that  will be updated with currently selected item and use two-way binding to have the selected item's Text property updated when Flyout text input changes. In case you need it i blogged about two way binding here: http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=81

Comment: Thinks a lot for this suggestion,it's very helpful , i think about MVVM but i was so busy to understang new concepts. I will test that.

Comment: In case you're insterested I've created a small MVVM framework: http://mvvmstack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

suggest use `data-win-bind` attribute in the flyout html. code below will display item.title property in the input element in the flyout

```
test.html:
<div class="edit-item" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout">
        <input type="text" class="item-text" data-win-bind="value: title" />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" />
</div>

test.js: event handler for iteminvoked event for the listview control
_oniteminvoked: function oniteminvoked(event)
{
    var item = this.items.getAt(event.detail.itemIndex); // assuming items is the list binding to the list view
    var editItemFlyoutElement = this.element.querySelector('.edit-item');
    WinJS.Binding.processAll(editItemFlyoutElement, item);
    editItemFlyoutElement.winControl.show(this.element);
}
```

HTH